# No Suitable application record were found. When Validating application - Beginner

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I need to validate my application (but not submit). So i build an archives file of the application and clicked on validate (in organizer).

I see a alert message saying

> No Suitable application record were found.
>
> Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on
>   iTunes connect.

I don't undestand what has gone wrong, can someone tell me what to do

note'\: i have googled and found similar questions, but none of then were helpful

Comment: Are you Registered Apple Developer (do you have Developer License (99$ per year))?

Comment: Yes i do. Once i click on Validate it prompts for dev id and password. after submitting that i get this error

Comment: No, how can i do that. Can you tell me the steps

Answer (score 2):

You have to register your app in iTunes Connect. This is an official Apple's document describing the process: **[iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (starting from page 37).**

Comment: The developer guide has moved: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/1_Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why it is happening like this and I have explained my case here.I faced same issue while I was updating my old application in iTunes Connect.I resolved that by putting some work by gone through some posts on web.We have one application in live store with one bundle id (com.sample.AppOne).We need 
to update the app to next version.Then I gave bundle id as 
(com.sample.AppNine) which does not match with the bundle in iTunes Connect 
earlier.So while updating the app in iTunes Connect we should give same bundle 
id which we gave for old version.This solved my issue.